# Rotate UIImageView in UITableViewCell - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an uiimageview in my uittableviewcell in my uitableview. What I want to accomplish is rotate all the uiimageviews of each cell using a timer. I know how the nstimer and rotating concept goes about, but I do not know how to rotate ALL the images in EACH cell in the UITableView. Is there a way to have access to these properties of all the uitableviewcells?

Hopefully this isn't confusing, and if it is here is a simple example:
Take for example I have 5 cells in my uitableview. each of the 5 cells has an uiimageview since my cells are customely made and has its own class. How would I rotate all 5 uiimageviews?

Thanks for all your help,

kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your timer callback function you want to do something like this.

```
NSArray* cellArray = [yourTableView visibleCells];
for (UITableViewCell* cell in cellArray)
{
  // do your cell by cell rotation here
}
```

To do this when you create your cell for an infinite animation you can use the following code.  Keep in mind that if you are caching cells then you only need to do this on cell creation, not on the cached cells.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"looping animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];     // 0 is infinite
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
// other animation options here if you'd like, and the duration can be anything, not just 3.

[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations: ^{
// do your rotation stuff on your image, in this block, for the cell you will be returning.

} completion:nil];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: It's possible that I'm misunderstanding, do you want to constantly rotate the views in all cells in an animation?  Or do it as a one time pass?  I don't understand enough context to know why you'd want to do this with a timer rather than rotating when creating your cells in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:...

Comment: I want the animation to continue even after that method.

Comment: In this case then it's simply a matter of iterating through all the cells each time your timer gets called and rotating the imageView on each cell.  You will want to have your own custom cell so you can rotate each custom view at that time.

Comment: The other option is you can use core animation's call animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
and pass in the repeat option.  If you do it this way you can do it when you create your custom cells in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and not have to use a timer.

Comment: Oh never though of that! thanks for the tip. Where would I initiate that method? Would I do it in my CustomCell class or in the cellforrowatindexPath? Would you provide a snippet of how the new method of rotating would look like with the animateWithDuration...

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to do this with the options.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer for animation isn't the best approach.

If you insist, I suggest you simply enumerate the visible cells (using the visibleCells tableview method) in the table view with each tick, and perform you rotation action on each cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about some methods of UIView which controls the animation flow? You can repeat the animation of rotating.